# decoding a complex string in haskell

Tags: json, haskell, getjson

I have made a json to haskell parser which is working absolutely correct and the parser is

```
decodeToMaybeValue::BLC.ByteString->Maybe Value                         
decodeToMaybeValue = decode

main = do                                               
    interact (show . decodeToMaybeValue . BLC.pack)
```

This is working absolutely correct when compiled on the compiler directly but when i try to store the string into a variable to decode it gives this error. I was trying this

```
x =`"{\"apiVersion\": \"2.0\",\"data\": {\"updated\": \"2010-01-07T19:58:42.949Z\",\"totalItems\": 800,\"startIndex\": 1,\"itemsPerPage\": 1,\"items\": [{\"id\": \"hYB0mn5zh2c\",\"uploaded\":\"2007-06-05T22:07:03.000Z\",\"updated\": \"2010-01-07T13:26:50.000Z\",\"uploader\": \"GoogleDeveloperDay\",\"category\": \"News\",\"title\": \"Google Developers Day US - Maps API Introduction\",\"description\": \"Google Maps API Introduction ...\",\"tags\": [\"GDD07\",\"GDD07US\",\"Maps\"],\"duration\": 2840,\"aspectRatio\": \"widescreen\",\"rating\": 4.63,\"ratingCount\": 68,\"viewCount\": 220101,\"favoriteCount\":201,\"commentCount\": 22 }]}}"`              
y = BLC.pack x                                                                                                

Invalid type signature: decode y :: Maybe Value
--    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
```

do anyone have idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't need to convert your string to Text if you use `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` at the top line of the file....

Is this what you want?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BLC

decodeToMaybeValue::BLC.ByteString->Maybe Value                         
decodeToMaybeValue = decode

theData="{\"a\": \"b\"}"  --Put in the data here.

main = do                                               
    print $ decodeToMaybeValue theData
```